# CRC32 Checksum Calculation via GO

Tags: linux, go

Trying to create a GO function that produces the same result as the Ubuntu Linux "cksum" operation, for example:

```
$ echo 123 > /tmp/foo
$ cksum /tmp/foo
2330645186 4 /tmp/foo
```

Could someone please provide a GO function that produces the first substring of the above result ("2330645186")? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a more simplified answer to my original question:

Using:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/cxmcc/unixsums#section-readme

Here is the snippet that provides the posix checksum equivalent value of a file in Go:

```golang
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/test.loop")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("cksum: %d\n", cksum.Cksum(data))
```

Answer (score 3):

(Update)

It turns out `cksum` doesn't implement a cyclic redundancy check based on the `CRC32` process (quite).  To test `CRC32` (the same as you'd find listed for a CRC32 checksum) you can use [CRC calculation @ http://zorc.breitbandkatze.de/](http://zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html) - go's *[`hash/crc32.ChecksumIEEE`](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/crc32/#ChecksumIEEE) implementation matches this*

To implement the `cksum` crc process (also known as `POSIX cksum`) I instead generated a golang version of the c algorithm found on a [cksum man page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/cksum.html) (which uses a lookup table)

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

var tbl = [256]uint32{0x00000000, 0x04C11DB7, 0x09823B6E, 0x0D4326D9,
    0x130476DC, 0x17C56B6B, 0x1A864DB2, 0x1E475005,
    0x2608EDB8, 0x22C9F00F, 0x2F8AD6D6, 0x2B4BCB61,
    0x350C9B64, 0x31CD86D3, 0x3C8EA00A, 0x384FBDBD,
    0x4C11DB70, 0x48D0C6C7, 0x4593E01E, 0x4152FDA9,
    0x5F15ADAC, 0x5BD4B01B, 0x569796C2, 0x52568B75,
    0x6A1936C8, 0x6ED82B7F, 0x639B0DA6, 0x675A1011,
    0x791D4014, 0x7DDC5DA3, 0x709F7B7A, 0x745E66CD,
    0x9823B6E0, 0x9CE2AB57, 0x91A18D8E, 0x95609039,
    0x8B27C03C, 0x8FE6DD8B, 0x82A5FB52, 0x8664E6E5,
    0xBE2B5B58, 0xBAEA46EF, 0xB7A96036, 0xB3687D81,
    0xAD2F2D84, 0xA9EE3033, 0xA4AD16EA, 0xA06C0B5D,
    0xD4326D90, 0xD0F37027, 0xDDB056FE, 0xD9714B49,
    0xC7361B4C, 0xC3F706FB, 0xCEB42022, 0xCA753D95,
    0xF23A8028, 0xF6FB9D9F, 0xFBB8BB46, 0xFF79A6F1,
    0xE13EF6F4, 0xE5FFEB43, 0xE8BCCD9A, 0xEC7DD02D,
    0x34867077, 0x30476DC0, 0x3D044B19, 0x39C556AE,
    0x278206AB, 0x23431B1C, 0x2E003DC5, 0x2AC12072,
    0x128E9DCF, 0x164F8078, 0x1B0CA6A1, 0x1FCDBB16,
    0x018AEB13, 0x054BF6A4, 0x0808D07D, 0x0CC9CDCA,
    0x7897AB07, 0x7C56B6B0, 0x71159069, 0x75D48DDE,
    0x6B93DDDB, 0x6F52C06C, 0x6211E6B5, 0x66D0FB02,
    0x5E9F46BF, 0x5A5E5B08, 0x571D7DD1, 0x53DC6066,
    0x4D9B3063, 0x495A2DD4, 0x44190B0D, 0x40D816BA,
    0xACA5C697, 0xA864DB20, 0xA527FDF9, 0xA1E6E04E,
    0xBFA1B04B, 0xBB60ADFC, 0xB6238B25, 0xB2E29692,
    0x8AAD2B2F, 0x8E6C3698, 0x832F1041, 0x87EE0DF6,
    0x99A95DF3, 0x9D684044, 0x902B669D, 0x94EA7B2A,
    0xE0B41DE7, 0xE4750050, 0xE9362689, 0xEDF73B3E,
    0xF3B06B3B, 0xF771768C, 0xFA325055, 0xFEF34DE2,
    0xC6BCF05F, 0xC27DEDE8, 0xCF3ECB31, 0xCBFFD686,
    0xD5B88683, 0xD1799B34, 0xDC3ABDED, 0xD8FBA05A,
    0x690CE0EE, 0x6DCDFD59, 0x608EDB80, 0x644FC637,
    0x7A089632, 0x7EC98B85, 0x738AAD5C, 0x774BB0EB,
    0x4F040D56, 0x4BC510E1, 0x46863638, 0x42472B8F,
    0x5C007B8A, 0x58C1663D, 0x558240E4, 0x51435D53,
    0x251D3B9E, 0x21DC2629, 0x2C9F00F0, 0x285E1D47,
    0x36194D42, 0x32D850F5, 0x3F9B762C, 0x3B5A6B9B,
    0x0315D626, 0x07D4CB91, 0x0A97ED48, 0x0E56F0FF,
    0x1011A0FA, 0x14D0BD4D, 0x19939B94, 0x1D528623,
    0xF12F560E, 0xF5EE4BB9, 0xF8AD6D60, 0xFC6C70D7,
    0xE22B20D2, 0xE6EA3D65, 0xEBA91BBC, 0xEF68060B,
    0xD727BBB6, 0xD3E6A601, 0xDEA580D8, 0xDA649D6F,
    0xC423CD6A, 0xC0E2D0DD, 0xCDA1F604, 0xC960EBB3,
    0xBD3E8D7E, 0xB9FF90C9, 0xB4BCB610, 0xB07DABA7,
    0xAE3AFBA2, 0xAAFBE615, 0xA7B8C0CC, 0xA379DD7B,
    0x9B3660C6, 0x9FF77D71, 0x92B45BA8, 0x9675461F,
    0x8832161A, 0x8CF30BAD, 0x81B02D74, 0x857130C3,
    0x5D8A9099, 0x594B8D2E, 0x5408ABF7, 0x50C9B640,
    0x4E8EE645, 0x4A4FFBF2, 0x470CDD2B, 0x43CDC09C,
    0x7B827D21, 0x7F436096, 0x7200464F, 0x76C15BF8,
    0x68860BFD, 0x6C47164A, 0x61043093, 0x65C52D24,
    0x119B4BE9, 0x155A565E, 0x18197087, 0x1CD86D30,
    0x029F3D35, 0x065E2082, 0x0B1D065B, 0x0FDC1BEC,
    0x3793A651, 0x3352BBE6, 0x3E119D3F, 0x3AD08088,
    0x2497D08D, 0x2056CD3A, 0x2D15EBE3, 0x29D4F654,
    0xC5A92679, 0xC1683BCE, 0xCC2B1D17, 0xC8EA00A0,
    0xD6AD50A5, 0xD26C4D12, 0xDF2F6BCB, 0xDBEE767C,
    0xE3A1CBC1, 0xE760D676, 0xEA23F0AF, 0xEEE2ED18,
    0xF0A5BD1D, 0xF464A0AA, 0xF9278673, 0xFDE69BC4,
    0x89B8FD09, 0x8D79E0BE, 0x803AC667, 0x84FBDBD0,
    0x9ABC8BD5, 0x9E7D9662, 0x933EB0BB, 0x97FFAD0C,
    0xAFB010B1, 0xAB710D06, 0xA6322BDF, 0xA2F33668,
    0xBCB4666D, 0xB8757BDA, 0xB5365D03, 0xB1F740B4}

type crc struct {
    p, r  uint32
    Size  int
    final bool
}

func NewCrc() *crc {
    return &crc{0, 0, 0, false}
}

func (pr *crc) Add(b byte) {
    if pr.final {
        return
    }
    pr.r = (pr.r << 8) ^ tbl[byte(pr.r>>24)^b]
    pr.Size++
}

func (pr *crc) Crc() uint32 {
    if pr.final {
        return pr.r
    }
    for m := pr.Size; m > 0; {
        b := byte(m & 0377)
        m = m >> 8
        pr.r = (pr.r << 8) ^ tbl[byte(pr.r>>24)^b]
    }
    pr.final = true //Prevent further modification
    pr.r = ^pr.r
    return pr.r

}

func cksum(filename string) (uint32, int, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, 0, err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    in := bufio.NewReader(f)
    pr := NewCrc()
    for done := false; !done; {
        switch b, err := in.ReadByte(); err {
        case io.EOF:
            done = true
        case nil:
            pr.Add(b)
        default:
            return 0, 0, err
        }
    }
    return pr.Crc(), pr.Size, nil
}

func main() {
    var filename = "foo"
    crc, size, err := cksum(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%d %d %s\n", crc, size, filename)
}
```

Obviously in this case the filename is hardcoded (to `foo`) but you could change that with flags. The content of foo is `123\n` (**note: in windows you'll need to convert line endings to not get a 5 byte file)  Results:

linux: `$ cksum foo`
`2330645186 4 foo`

linux: `$ go run cksum.go`
`2330645186 4 foo`

windows: `> go run cksum.go` **
`2330645186 4 foo`

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, below is what I did, but I still do not see the result of the "cksum /tmp/foo" ("2330645186"):

`
tablePolynomial := crc32.MakeTable(0x04C11DB7)
dat, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/foo")
cksum := crc32.Checksum(dat, tablePolynomial)
fmt.Println("cksum =", cksum)
`

The above snippet prints:
cksum = 4227056743